# Prove that elementary tensor is non-zero in proof of non-flatness

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, flatness

This is a follow-up question to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2531475/non-flatness-of-kt-as-a-kt2-t3-module) (and the answer there by René Schipperus) about proving that $k[t]$ is non-flat as $k[t^2,t^3]$-module.

I have reduced this to showing that $t\otimes t$ is non-zero in $k[t]/(t^2)\otimes_{k[t^2,t^3]} k[t]$. To show that an elementary tensor is non-zero, I have to find a $k[t^2,t^3]$-bilinear map from $k[t]/(t^2) \times k[t]$ to an abelian group such that the image of $(t,t)$ is non-zero.

Does someone have a hint?

Comment: Let $a: k[T]\to k$ mapping $f$ to $f'(0)$, it is $k[T^2, T^3]=R$-linear, where you view $k$ as a $R$-module where $T^2$ and $T^3$ act trivially, you can consider $k[T]/(T^2)\times k[T] \to k[T]/(T^2)\times k\to k[T]/(T^2)$, where the map on the left is $1\otimes a$ and the second is the multiplication, it is clearly $k$-linear and in fact $R$-linear as $t^2, t^3$ both act trivially.

Comment: @Ahr What do you mean by "act trivially"?

Comment: I mean acts by multiplication by 0.

Comment: But then $1x=x$ axiom implies then $1=0$ right ? But this is not true in $k$ ?

Comment: It looks like you might have meant to link to another question?

Comment: @Badam yes, I edited, thanks :-)

Comment: I mean that $T^2$ and $T^3$ acts by multiplication by $0$, not all $R$.

Comment: If you prefer you view $k$ as an $R$-module via $R\times k\to k$ given by $(f,\alpha)\mapsto f(0).\alpha$, you clearly have $T^2.\alpha=T^3.\alpha=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=k[t]/(t^2)$ and $u=[t]\in A$ satisfying $u^2=0$. 
The action is given by $f\cdot(a+bu)=f(u)\cdot(a+bu)$ for $f\in k[t]$, in particular $f=t^2$ annihilates all of $A$.

Then consider $\varphi:A\times k[t]\to A$ mapping
$$(a+bu,\,f)\,\mapsto\,b\cdot f(u)$$
We get $\varphi((a+bu)c,\,f)=\varphi(a+bu,\,cf)$ for any $c\in k$, and the actions of $t^2,t^3$ make both sides $0$, so it's $k[t^2,t^3]$-bilinear, and it maps
$$\varphi([t],\,t)=\varphi(u,t)=1\cdot u=u\,\ne 0\,.$$

Comment: Note that $b=(a+bt)'(0)$, so it's basically the same answer as in the comments.

Comment: Thank you Berci !